# do cable modems log what ips they are assigned by the isp?

Tags: dhcp, logging, modem, dynamic-ip

just out of curiosity. i've been looking at various modem manufacturers' websites and it seems clear that there are firewall logs and event logs but i don't know whether the event logs would cover the pppoe or dhcp assignment on the part of the isp.

the router i'm curious about is the siemens speedstream 6520...

Answer (score 1):

If you have the router, you could try viewing the syslog logs directly from another machine using these steps:

> 1. Configure syslogd on a machine and
>    do not forget to allow it to receive
>    log data from remote hosts (-r on Unix
>    syslogd).
> 2. Open the telnet console for the device
>    (requires knowledge of the telnet user and
>    passwd).
> 3. Enter the following command: xsh> **cfg slog{ip=a.b.c.d**,
>    where a.b.c.d is the ip address of the
>    system running syslogd.

From this [thread](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/415042.html).